# Nginx reverse proxy for docker web services

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, mediawiki, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx as reverse proxy with ssl to access my locally running web services deployed by docker containers. When specifying locations in nginx, I don't only get the start page of the server but I am not able to follow any links on that page. Besides that, Images of my web service are not displayed.

I have already read the nginx documentation and tried out a lot of different things. For instance, when I am just omitting the location, the web service runs perfectly fine.

Working example of the nginx.conf:

```sh
location /{
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7081/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  }
```

Not Working example of the nginx.conf:

```sh
  location /wiki/ {
    rewrite ^/wiki(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7081/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  }
```

I am obviously missing something in the latter example. Does anyone know, what I am missing, so that I can simply proxy pass request directly to my dockerized web service?

EDIT:
Here a more and hopefully reproducible example:

The docker container I launched, was simply a base MediaWiki which was published internally on localhost on port 7081.

```sh
docker run --name some-mediawiki -p 127.0.0.1:7081:80 -d mediawiki
```

The file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` looks like this:

```sh
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.de; 
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } 

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name my.domain.de*;

  # SSL-Certificate and key
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/my_full_chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/my-key.pem;

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s;

  location /wiki {
    rewrite ^/wiki(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7081/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with `docker-compose` for instance?

Comment: `location /wiki` ? try o remove the last `/`

Comment: Thank you. Removing the `/` made the images appear. But I am still not able to follow links on that page.

Comment: I was simply using the default docker image for media wiki to launch some web application. I will provide a minimal example in my updated post in just a second.

Comment: The question was updated with a hopefully reproducible example

Comment: what links you talking about ?

Comment: Any links on the launched web sites which direct me to another page.

Comment: The problem is actually equal to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/748346/nginx-reverse-proxy-not-loading-resources/980878#980878)